# Unable to integrate OIDC app with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have created a spring boot OIDC app (added directory id, tanent id and client secret key in application.properties) to integrate in azure AD tenant and configured it. Our OIDC app url is https://oidctest.com/oidc. But we are having an issue while trying to authenticate an user using azure ad. An internal redirection is happening in an url which is not https rather http url (http://oidctest.com/login/oauth2/code/azure).  As per azure ad configuration the redirection should be happened in https url i.e https://oidctest.com/login/oauth2/code/azure. It seems that due to this incompatibility we are getting an exception that **the reply url doesn't match with the url mentioned in azure ad configuartion**. From network tab I am getting this,

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=e4d498e4-1234-42ae-890b-505b93928bce&scope=openid%20https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read&state=YOXf51biLBUPZy0yb92ymnwN2M1TDuWdSK5qRwstpKc%3D&redirect_uri=http://oidctest.com/login/oauth2/code/azure

Please note : this is working expected in case of http (in case of localhost). In azure ad portal configuration reply urls are mentioned correctly which we have verified already.

**Error message is** ,

Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'e4d478e4-c8aa-42ae-890b-505b93928bce'.

Request Id: cd6e86e4-5edf-40eb-b135-86f65262b500
Correlation Id: 694635ef-0924-4650-9991-c1edc2deb764
Timestamp: 2019-09-17T10:51:22Z
Message: AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'e4d478e4-c8aa-42ae-890b-505b93928bce'.
Advanced diagnostics: Enable
If you plan on getting support for an issue, turn this on and try to reproduce the error. This will collect additional information that will help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Your app code seems to be doing something wrong, if it is sending the wrong reply URL to AAD. Could you add some of that code here?

Comment: hi @juunas my code is working as expected in case of http url (in case of localhost). This is a simple spring boot hello world example. To make it oidc enable we have integrated webSecurityConfig class which is like below,

Comment: Hi @juunas I am not able to upload that snippet but this is nothing but a class WebSecurityConfig which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and this is available here in this url, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory?view=azure-java-stable#create-azure-active-directory-instance .. I have followed these steps only.

Comment: Okay, do you define the redirect URL in that config? Does it have http or https?

Comment: hi @juunas, yes, I have defined it in config as https.